# Does sonarqube version 3.7.3 support java 1.7?

Tags: java, jenkins, sonarqube

There is a requirement to run the Project with Java 1.7 on Hudson/Jenkins and the Sonar version that we have is SonarQube 3.7.3.
So does this version of Sonar(3.7.3) support java 1.7?

Also, if not, then can we run 2 sonar servers as there are multiple projects that still run on Java 6 and only for 1 project, it would not be feasible to upgrade the Sonar version if the existing version is not compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for Java 7 was added in [Sonar 2.12](http://www.sonarqube.org/sonar-2-12-in-screenshots/). Also see the related [Jira story](http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-2584).